# facebook redirect_uri not working for mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a facebook canvas app and I'm running both the same code and same redirect_uri for web and mobile, it works without issue in my web configuration but my mobile version doesn't. My app is a responsive app, so even the URLs within the facebook configuration are identical.

The method I'm using for both to generate the url

```
List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<>();
            qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", facebookClientId));
            qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "https://apps.facebook.com/customdomain"));
            qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", facebookClientSecret));
            qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));

            uri = new URIBuilder()
                    .setScheme("https")
                    .setHost("graph.facebook.com")
                    .setPath("/oauth/access_token")
                    .setParameters(qparams)
                    .build(); 

website url https://local.mydomain.com:8443/test/facebook/auth

mobile url https://local.mydomain.com:8443/test/facebook/auth
```

**Canvas URL**

```
https://local.mydomain.com:8443/test/facebook/auth/
```

**auth urls**

```
https://local.mydomain.com:8443/test/facebook/auth/
https://apps.facebook.com/customdomain
```

**App domain**

```
https://apps.facebook.com/customdomain
```

**Working url from website**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=578152068997908&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fmydomain&client_secret=xxxx&code=AQBQ_VZlxKWqMfmC2neu8DIllor0Lrp1wvLvtSD5do3PyMfO_jxiEjcGEbZ-a0bEJbe6Ya9Noh9esXm2mgmgw0zP9OQOM-2h7VBYkruix0o7isKWwYkksFAi-i2qpUmTBcb0YxAqrn5y2aEWk8GxmhEVAgsW3GGLksNTndhZr3NYDs5Mi4GtmsjMKJbO8dTzePDrh4iSz_Qv0fmgalkDhIRmM7zsjodFPkytL4rlzG9Q4oN14qEhpBUmISnu8cAQcLvOlYACD17nFqhyq-BOVmX8PpUNRFdoHDk9KUTUv7c8PbfVGOBmWeJJKxWdZ0ncUu0
```

**Non working mobile**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=578152068997908&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fmydomain&client_secret=xxxx&code=AQBQ_VZlxKWqMfmC2neu8DIllor0Lrp1wvLvtSD5do3PyMfO_jxiEjcGEbZ-a0bEJbe6Ya9Noh9esXm2mgmgw0zP9OQOM-2h7VBYkruix0o7isKWwYkksFAi-i2qpUmTBcb0YxAqrn5y2aEWk8GxmhEVAgsW3GGLksNTndhZr3NYDs5Mi4GtmsjMKJbO8dTzePDrh4iSz_Qv0fmgalkDhIRmM7zsjodFPkytL4rlzG9Q4oN14qEhpBUmISnu8cAQcLvOlYACD17nFqhyq-BOVmX8PpUNRFdoHDk9KUTUv7c8PbfVGOBmWeJJKxWdZ0ncUu0
```

**Response**

```
InternalModule.PageLoader Loaded page 'facebook/Auth' (en) in 112.543 ms
response HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request", Facebook-API-Version: v1.0, Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8, Pragma: no-cache, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, X-FB-Rev: 1514665, Cache-Control: no-store, Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT, X-FB-Debug: WpyeYYw/BIs08HkafBWcrkbU5tICVgEHTKrPBAiTzZEqjgP3OGCP8eQwNVx2lx6b0iH9GGqIrir3S4iGu7VAIw==, Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2014 09:21:50 GMT, Connection: keep-alive, Content-Length: 190]}
facebook.FacebookAuth com.mydomain.test.pages.facebook.FacebookAuth 400 HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request", Facebook-API-Version: v1.0, Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8, Pragma: no-cache, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, X-FB-Rev: 1514665, Cache-Control: no-store, Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT, X-FB-Debug: WpyeYYw/BIs08HkafBWcrkbU5tICVgEHTKrPBAiTzZEqjgP3OGCP8eQwNVx2lx6b0iH9GGqIrir3S4iGu7VAIw==, Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2014 09:21:50 GMT, Connection: keep-alive, Content-Length: 190]}
facebook.FacebookAuth com.mydomain.test.pages.facebook.FacebookAuth
```

What could possible be causing this issue? Does it have something to do with canvas and mobile?

Comment: Could it be that a trailing / is needed after the redirect uri? example https://apps.facebook.com/mydomain/ If that is the case I wonder why it would work with the website and not the mobile version? Also, how would the security parameter be handled then. https://apps.facebok.com/mydomain/client_secret?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, make sure your redirect url matches the facebook redirect url. It's been a while, but I'm pretty certain that was my issue.